# how to get the background color in figma that appear as photo?

Tags: css, web, frontend, figma

I'm trying to get the background color which is linear gradient from [this template](https://www.figma.com/file/6DeOGqcKRgnraPT9ivDqaR/Signup-Flow-UI-(Community)?node-id=106%3A317&t=i2TwZseikSQFU3yc-0) but it appear as background image , any help please?

Comment: I think it's actually a static image. You may need to ask the designer for their recipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Figma, images are actually a type of shape fill. Like colors or gradients.

In the template you linked, you can replace the gradient background with a different one, like a photo background.

This technique won't create a separate layer for the image. Instead, it's a fill for the parent frame.

**Steps:**

1. On that file, go a blank area and then insert the photo/picture that you actually want as the new background image for the webpage design.
2. Select the photo/picture.
3. On the fill panel, click leftmost part of the Image fill to select it. Then press `CTRL+C` to copy it.

[image]

5. Select the background frame that has the gradient.
6. On the Fill Panel, delete the Image. Because the gradient design is actually a pasted image.

[image]

7. With the background frame still selected, press `CTRL+V`.

[image]